# Ошибка при реализации стека

Tags: c++

Почему он сохраняет только 1 элемент, и именно последний который был дан с помощью функции push

```
template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::isempty() {
    return size == 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::push(T& item) {
    T* buffer; // буффер для данных из stack
    buffer = stack;
    stack = new T[size + 1]; // выделяем память на 1 элемент больше чем было
    if (stack == NULL) {
        cout << "Error\n";
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        stack[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    stack[size] = item;
    size++; // увеличваем количество элементов
    if (size > 0)
        delete[] buffer;
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
int Stack<T>::size_stack() {
    return size;
}

template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (size == 0) // стек пуст
        return 0;
    size--;
    return stack[size];
}

template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::head() {
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;
    return stack[size - 1];
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::Print() {
    T* buff; // указатель для продвижения по стеку
    buff = stack;
    cout << "Stack" << endl;
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "items[" << i << "] = " << *buff << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам там array? если вам нужен просто стек возьмете форвар лист) зачем вам произвольный доступ?

Comment: потому что buffer и stack всегда равны

Comment: stack = new T[size + 1]; не много алокаций то?)))) как то не оч эффективно - вы на С++ же пишете - подумайте о скорости работы - каждый пуш это аллокация + memmove - такое себе.... + давайте подумаем о кейсе где сначала сделали pop а потом push - как то вы раскидываетесь свободной памятью - капасипи прикапывайте то роди приличия то)

Comment: А как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: @RumeOne посмотреть уже нормальные реализации а не велосипеды стоить)

Comment: @Maggot нормальная имплементация для школьного урока информатики. В прод конечно такого никто не пустит, но для школьного учителя - самое оно.

Answer (score 3):

`cout << "items[" << i << "] = " << *buff << endl;` - попробуйте `<< *buff++ <<`, а то у вас указатель всегда на один и тот же элемент указывает. Или `<< buff[i] <<`

Но только вот у вас несообразностей все равно много.

Например, вы не сможете сделать в `Stack<int>` - `push(1)`, потому что передаете неконстантную ссылку.

`push()` у вас возвращает `bool`, а `pop` в случае неприятности - 0. А Если этот 0 нельзя привести к типу `T`? А если это `int` - то возврат 0 означает, что там был 0, или что там не было ничего? Где же **логика**? (О безопасности в смысле исключений промолчу - но задумайтесь: в стандартном стеке есть отдельно функция возврата элемента на вершине, и отдельно - ничего не возвращающая функция `pop`. И это неспроста :))

Об эффективности вам уже рассказали в комментариях; добавлю только, что при `pop` вы саму память не уменьшаете. Представим, что у вас было в стеке 100 элементов. Вы оттуда забрали 100. Итог? Есть заполненный наполовину массив. Есть место для 100 элементов - но вы все равно будете при добавлении выполнять выделение массива под 101 элемент... :( Опять - не логичнее ли следить, сколько есть места, сколько занято - и выделять память, когда она нужна, а не просто так...

Comment: кстати а поч std::stack на деке по дефолту сделан? нафига там произвольный доступ то?) Или они капасити так увеличывают блоком дека?

Comment: Плюс в методе `head()` очень странно выглядит строка `return stack[size - 1];`

Comment: а `*buff[i]` опечатка?

Comment: а push возвратит false только в очень экзотических условиях. так что там можно выкинуть половину кода

Comment: @Bogdan Да, конечно.

Comment: @Maggot Ну, в принципе, можно на векторе, исходя из того, что только с одной стороны работа...

Comment: @Harry все варно много алоков

Answer (score 2):

@Harry все хорошо написал, вот только он не написал, почему же в стеке получается мусор (собственно сам вопрос). А он спрятан в этой конструкции

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    stack[i] = buffer[i];
}
```

последний элемент не копируется. Таким образом в нем будет мусор. А так как при каждой вставке не копируется предыдущий элемент, то весь стек, кроме вставляемого элемента содержит мусор.

Исправить просто

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    stack[i] = buffer[i];
}
```

или если гулять так гулять, то даже так

```
memcpy(stack, buffer, sizeof(T)*size);
```

Comment: вариант с memcpy и или с меммув лучше) а еще есть реалок)

Comment: realloc не работает с new. memmove ... я думал написать std::copy, но решил что на общем фоне будет выглядеть странно

Comment: ну я же не говорю писать с реалок) ну обернуть там нью + меммув)